# Editing a module's css/xhtml in joomla 1.7

Tags: templates, module, joomla, xampp

LIke the title says, how do i edit the xhtml/css of a module in the joomla 1.7 interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can simply create additional CSS file (or even include to your existing one) for your template.

Firstly using Firebug/Chrome find the CSS path to your module. ex. "**div.container div.mod-languages**"

Secondly create some CSS rules for your module:

```
div.container div.mod-languages {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #DADADA;
}
```

Additionaly you can add "**!important**" declaration to your rules to make sure they have higher priority to "default joomla's rules", example:

```
position: relative !important;
```